# Tool for cleaning installed fonts

Tags: package-management, fonts, administration, tools

I have have **installed too much fonts** (11.10); now my system is very slow (memory full, etc.). Does a tool exist in order to **clean my mess up**?

Answer (score 1):

Font manager, which is available in the repos, is what youre looking for. [Click here to install it.](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/font-manager)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Font Manager currently allows the user to:

```
    Preview installed fonts
    Compare installed fonts
    Easily install or remove fonts
    Easily activate and de-activate installed fonts
    Specify different directories to search for fonts
    Group fonts into "Collections", and easily activate or de-activate groups of fonts
    Export "Collections" to an archive for easy backup, sharing, etc.
    Provides quick access to all GNOME font utilities.
```

- available in the software repositories or download [HERE](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/font-manager)